# Can I demultiplex streams?

Tags: java, stream, io

I want to join stderr (`getErrorStream`) and stdout (`getInputStream`) of a `Process` into a single `Stream` to be consumed elsewhere. Is there anything in Java's library that will do that for me?

Note: *no external libraries*. I'm not interested in the existence of a solution provided by, say, Apache Commons IO. I only want to know if there's something that comes with JDK.

Comment: Did you tried [ProcessBuilder.redirectErrorStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectErrorStream(boolean)) ?

Comment: @GabrielBelingueres I think that's too early in the process for me. I don't think I can move the decision to the owner of the `ProcessBuilder`, but I'll look into it.

Comment: does it have to be stout and sterr?

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer They are the "stdout" and "stderr" of a `Process`.

Answer (score 1):

[`ProcessBuilder.redirectErrorStream(boolean)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectErrorStream%28boolean%29) does what you want.

> `public ProcessBuilder redirectErrorStream(boolean redirectErrorStream)`
>
> Sets this process builder's `redirectErrorStream` property.
>
> If this property is `true`, then any error output generated by subprocesses subsequently started by this object's `start()` method will be merged with the standard output, so that both can be read using the `Process.getInputStream()` method. This makes it easier to correlate error messages with the corresponding output. The initial value is `false`.

EDIT: @Since Java 5 or later so should be widely available.

Comment: Doesn't work for me: both streams have to be generated, passed to other objects separately, and then finally to the point where I have to join them to feed another process.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a SequenceInputStream to merge the 2 InputStream.

Comment: Not satisfactory -- that's not demultiplexing, just serializing.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no thing that does that in the JDK (up until 6, in 7 I haven't looked at every class yet).